# invalid statement in fillwindow() in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, memory-leaks

I newbie in Android and before ask question here i was googling, but on this question i can't find answer. (also this stackoverflow.com/questions/4195089 don't have answer).

In my test app on emulator i have error **ERROR/Cursor(1512): Invalid statement in fillWindow()** on LogCat when i press back button on second activity.
<sub>*11-23 19:06:05.050: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): onCreate

11-23 19:06:06.820: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): openDataBase

11-23 19:06:07.240: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): String[] from

11-23 19:06:07.270: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): SimpleCursorAdapter

11-23 19:06:07.500: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): myDbHelper.close

11-23 19:06:07.520: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): onStart

11-23 19:06:07.551: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): onResume

11-23 19:06:09.040: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Displayed activity ru.olegi/.MainActivity: 7962 ms

11-23 19:06:11.850: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Starting activity: Intent { comp={ru.olegi/ru.olegi.AnotherActivity} }

11-23 19:06:12.100: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/AnotherActivity(1512): onCreate

11-23 19:06:12.970: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Displayed activity ru.olegi/.AnotherActivity: 1100 ms

11-23 19:06:14.550: ERROR/Cursor(1512): Invalid statement in fillWindow()

11-23 19:06:14.590: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): onStart

11-23 19:06:14.600: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(1512): onResume*</sub>

All code stored in onCreate. So when i press back, ListView is empty. For fix this i move code to onStart. Here is log for this and again have Invalid statement in fillWindow()

<sub>*11-23 19:26:06.280: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): onCreate

11-23 19:26:06.462: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): onStart

11-23 19:26:06.700: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): openDataBase

11-23 19:26:06.740: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): String[] from

11-23 19:26:06.750: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): SimpleCursorAdapter

11-23 19:26:06.981: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): myDbHelper.close

11-23 19:26:07.010: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): onResume

11-23 19:26:08.030: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Displayed activity ru.olegi/.MainActivity: 3876 ms

11-23 19:26:15.419: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Starting activity: Intent { comp={ru.olegi/ru.olegi.AnotherActivity} }

11-23 19:26:15.770: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/AnotherActivity(6597): onCreate

11-23 19:26:16.440: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Displayed activity ru.olegi/.AnotherActivity: 1001 ms

11-23 19:26:17.860: ERROR/Cursor(6597): Invalid statement in fillWindow()

11-23 19:26:17.870: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): onStart

11-23 19:26:18.260: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): openDataBase

11-23 19:26:18.290: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): String[] from

11-23 19:26:18.310: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): SimpleCursorAdapter

11-23 19:26:18.670: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): myDbHelper.close

11-23 19:26:18.700: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(6597): onResume*</sub>

This code

```
package ru.olegi;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private DatabaseHelper myDbHelper;  
    private ListView lv1;   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onCreate");          

        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onStart");

        // DATABASE OPEN - START
        DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }          

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }        

        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "openDataBase");        

        // DATABASE OPEN - END

        Cursor c = myDbHelper.fetchAllFoodname();
        startManagingCursor(c);                       

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1};

        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "String[] from");

        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to);

        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "SimpleCursorAdapter");

        lv1.setAdapter(notes);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {      
            //@Override     
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();

                //getApplicationContext()
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);

                //intent.putExtra(AnotherActivity.EXT_ID, id);              

                startActivity(intent);
                //finish(); 
            }   
         });   

        // DATABASE CLOSE - START       

        myDbHelper.close();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "myDbHelper.close");

        // DATABASE CLOSE - END         
    }    

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onResume"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onDestroy");        
    }        
}
```

Here groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8bec793c626fb405 i read, for fix fillwindow() error need

> Short answer; Your database object
>   (db) is in the wrong scope.  Longer
>   answer; By declaring db in the method
>   you're saying to the JVM  that when
>   the method finishes your database
>   connection (db) is no  longer useful.
>   What you should do is declare db at
>   the class level  instead of the method
>   level, create it in onCreate, and
>   close it in  onDestroy.

Ok, i move sections // DATABASE OPEN - START and // DATABASE CLOSE - START to onCreate and to onDestory. And now i have exception on start

<sub>*11-23 19:35:39.310: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(8975): onCreate

11-23 19:35:40.050: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(8975): openDataBase

11-23 19:35:40.050: DEBUG/TestDB/Debug/MainActivity(8975): onStart

11-23 19:35:40.090: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8975): Shutting down VM

11-23 19:35:40.100: WARN/dalvikvm(8975): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)

11-23 19:35:40.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.olegi/ru.olegi.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at ru.olegi.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:59)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1205)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3490)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)

11-23 19:35:40.300: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8975):     ... 11 more*</sub>

Here is code with moved db-sections:

```
package ru.olegi;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private DatabaseHelper myDbHelper;  
    private ListView lv1;   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onCreate");          

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // DATABASE OPEN - START
        DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }          

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }        

        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "openDataBase");        

        // DATABASE OPEN - END


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onStart");

        Cursor c = myDbHelper.fetchAllFoodname();
        startManagingCursor(c);                       

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

        String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1};

        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "String[] from");

        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to);

        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "SimpleCursorAdapter");

        lv1.setAdapter(notes);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {      
            //@Override     
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();

                //getApplicationContext()
                intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);

                //intent.putExtra(AnotherActivity.EXT_ID, id);              

                startActivity(intent);
                //finish(); 
            }   
         });   

    }    

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onResume"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "onDestroy");

        // DATABASE CLOSE - START       

        myDbHelper.close();
        Log.d("TestDB/Debug/MainActivity", "myDbHelper.close");

        // DATABASE CLOSE - END     
    }        
}
```

Please, help fix **Invalid statement in fillWindow()**

AnotherActivity - is simple with TextView, MainActivity have only listview + onclick listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private DatabaseHelper myDbHelper; 
...
public void onStart() {
     DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

I removed the declaration DatabaseHelper in onStart. That fixed the ERROR/Cursor(1512)